# (g)awk seems to cache output of shell commands - how to avoid that?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a weird problem with gawk and I don't know if it's a bug or awk's default behavior that I just don't understand. Basically when I execute a shell command in an awk script and capture its output with `getline`, all consecutive calls of that command seem to yield the same output as the first one. Here's an example:

```
# <foo.awk 

BEGIN {
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    "date +%s" | getline sec
    print sec
    system("sleep 1")
  }
}
# gawk -f foo.awk
1436437519
1436437519
1436437519
1436437519
1436437519
#
```

I'd like to know whether this behavior is intentional and explained somewhere in a manual (I couldn't find anything) and if there's a way to work around it.

Comment: Just wondering why don't you run date with system() like you do with sleep?

Comment: In testing on CentOs I found that sec increments every pass with system("date +%s") but an extra line with a 0 gets generated.  That can be removed with tr -d '\n' but then each pass takes 10 seconds.  The best solution is just to print systime() directly for a report of time increments by seconds.

Comment: @TrisNefzger Because I need the output of the command, which system() doesn't give me. Also "date +%s" was just an example to illustrate the problem, in my actual script I'm running a different command that has nothing to do with time.

Answer (score 4):

You have to close() the pipe when you are done with each execution of the command:

```
$ cat foo.awk
BEGIN {
  cmd = "date +%s"
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cmd | getline sec
    print sec
    close(cmd)
    system("sleep 1")
  }
}

$ awk -f foo.awk
1436451378
1436451379
1436451380
1436451381
1436451382
```

Make sure you read and fully understand the sections on `getline` in the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins (especially http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe) AND fully understand everything at http://awk.info/?tip/getline if you are considering using getline and then usually you'll realize there's a better approach.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I somehow missed that I have to close the pipe.